# Change size of callout from Yandex API

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mapkit, yandex-api

I need change frame for callout, that is in Yandex API. Maybe there are other ways to reduce size of callout without methods from this API?

[image]

The width of callout must be 2/3 width of window.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of custom callout libraries on GitHub.  I think this one might serve your needs:

https://github.com/grgcombs/MultiRowCalloutAnnotationView

Google around a bit and you can find a bunch more

Comment: And how I will change thw view of callout? What pattern I need use? I need categories?

Comment: I use https://github.com/farcaller/motion-yandexmapkit/tree/master/YandexMapKit.
So the most ineresting in YMKAnnotationView.h and YMKCalloutView.h I think